# How can I use fixtures in Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Does anybody can get me started on using fixtures in doctrine 2? In doctrine 1 this was easy. But in the doctrine 2 documentation there's nothing I can find about fixtures.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

YAML data fixtures no longer exist in Doctrine 2.

you can use use regular PHP code to load data fixtures.

see this link

http://www.symfony-project.org/blog/2009/10/05/symfony-and-doctrine-2

Comment: Thanks this helped me out. In the comments there was a link to a class that makes it possible to still use YAML fixtures. https://gist.github.com/9a677147c42e5fed7d05

Answer (score 4):

There are now data fixtures for Doctrine 2:
https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up [Migrations](http://doctrine-migrations.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/introduction.html) and creating some 'fixture' Migrations.  This is the best approach I've encountered thus far (however I'm using Zend Framework, Haim's suggestion may be better if you're using Symfony).